# How to read a file and send as stream to another endpoint

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-ftp

I need to read a file using apache camel and send to another endpoint as stream.

```
public class SimpleRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:C:/inputFolder?noop=true").to("streamEndPoint");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you finally answer what must be done with data from consumed file ? What is your abstract "stream endponit" ? Is this [camel-stream](http://camel.apache.org/stream.html) ? Many of you question were answered but you continue asking question similar to each other.

Comment: streamEndpoint is something like rest service.                                                                                         from("file:C:/inputFolder?noop=true").to(processor).to("streamEndPoint");

Comment: Ок so stop calling it streamendpoint =) You need example of consuming file and sending it as attach to rest service , isn't it ? I'll try to give you working example a little bit later.

Answer (score 0):

Here some simple working example of routes from(file).to(rest-service)

```
      //receiver
      from("jetty://http://0.0.0.0:5514/path/getFile")
            .process(exchange -> {
                if (exchange.getIn().getAttachments() != null) {
                    for (String key : exchange.getIn().getAttachments().keySet()) {
                        DataHandler dataHandler = exchange.getIn().getAttachments().get(key);
                        System.out.println(String.format("Receive attachment:%s size:%s", dataHandler.getName(), dataHandler.getInputStream().available()));
                    }
                }
            });


    //sender
    from("file:/Users/user1/test/?delete=true&delay=5000")
            .process(exchange -> {
                GenericFile<File> body = exchange.getIn().getBody(GenericFile.class);
                exchange.getIn().setHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
                exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", "POST");
                exchange.getIn().setBody(MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                        .addPart(body.getFileName(), new FileBody(body.getFile(), ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, body.getFileName()))
                        .build()
                );
            })
            .to("http4://0.0.0.0:5514/path/getFile?synchronous=true")//camel-http4 component for sending to our rest service

    ;
```

Here is whole [example](https://gist.github.com/c0ldd/7d6b8327a00dda0fd2b4c4fff0d87a4f) that you can run and see how it works.